# error: cannot access InternalTokenProvider class file for com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider not found

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I wanted to implement a test cloud message in my app. So I had gone through the official documentation

here is my main activity

```
    package com.technolgiya.quickbooktechnichian;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView navView;
    private ImageView logoutBtn;
    DatabaseReference user;
    private RecyclerView findJob;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    private DatabaseReference jobreq;
    private String subAdmin = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create channel to show notifications.
            String channelId  = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
            String channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW));
        }

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                Log.d("KEYY", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }
        }


        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
        logoutBtn = findViewById(R.id.logout_btn);
        findJob = findViewById(R.id.newrequest_job);
        findJob.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<JobRequest> options = null;

        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(logoutIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
                {

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.navigation_home :
                            Intent jobintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(jobintent);
                            break;

                        case R.id.navigation_dashboard :

                            user = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                            user.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                        {
                                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                                            {
                                                String phoneNumber = dataSnapshot.child("phoneNumber").getValue().toString();

                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                Intent callprofile = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                                                callprofile.putExtra("phoneNumber",phoneNumber);
                                                startActivity(callprofile);


                                            }


                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                            break;

                        case R.id.navigation_notifications :
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Log.w("Token", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                                                return;
                                            }

                                            // Get new Instance ID token
                                            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                                            // Log and toast
                                            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
                                            Log.d("Tokkken", msg);
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                            break;

                        case R.id.navigation_billing :
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "billing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;


                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        userRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {

                            String nameDb = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            //  Toast.makeText(ServiceproviderActivity.this, nameDb, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            subAdmin = dataSnapshot.child("subAdmin").getValue().toString();

                            jobreq = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location").child(subAdmin).child("JobRequest").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<JobRequest> options = null;

                            options =
                                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<JobRequest>()
                                            .setQuery(jobreq, JobRequest.class)
                                            .build();


                            final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JobRequest, MainActivity.FindJobViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                                    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JobRequest, MainActivity.FindJobViewHolder>(options) {
                                @Override
                                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainActivity.FindJobViewHolder holder,
                                                                final int position,
                                                                @NonNull final JobRequest modelLoc)
                                {
                                    final String listUserId = getRef(position).getKey();

                                    jobreq.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                        {
                                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                                            {


                                                    holder.client_name.setText(modelLoc.getClientName());
                                                    holder.senderAddress.setText(modelLoc.getClientAddress());
                                                    holder.job_description.setText(modelLoc.getJobdescription());
                                                    holder.request_status.setText(modelLoc.getStatus());
                                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, listUserId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No request Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                    holder.jobstarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")
                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                            String msg = "Successfull";
                                                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                msg = "msg subscribed failed";
                                                            }
                                                            Log.d("message", msg);
                                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                            // [END subscribe_topics]


                                        }
                                    });


                                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            holder.getAdapterPosition();

                                            String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked on:" + visit_user_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                                @NonNull
                                @Override
                                public MainActivity.FindJobViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup p, int viewType) {
                                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(p.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.jobrequest_design, p, false);
                                    MainActivity.FindJobViewHolder viewHolder = new MainActivity.FindJobViewHolder(view);
                                    return viewHolder;
                                }

                            };
                            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
                            findJob.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


        super.onStart();
    }

    public static class FindJobViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        RelativeLayout cardViewLocation;
        TextView senderAddress;
        TextView client_name;
        TextView job_description;
        TextView request_status;
        Button jobstarted;

        public FindJobViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cardViewLocation=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_location);
            senderAddress=itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_address);
            client_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_name);
            job_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_description);
            request_status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_status);
            jobstarted = itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept_job);



        }
    }


    

}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingclass

```
   package com.technolgiya.quickbooktechnichian;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.technolgiya.quickbooktechnichian.R;

import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;

/**
 * NOTE: There can only be one service in each app that receives FCM messages. If multiple
 * are declared in the Manifest then the first one will be chosen.
 *
 * In order to make this Java sample functional, you must remove the following from the Kotlin messaging
 * service in the AndroidManifest.xml:
 *
 * <intent-filter>
 *   <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
 * </intent-filter>
 */
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages
        // are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data
        // messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in
        // onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated
        // notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages
        // containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always
        // sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]


    // [START on_new_token]

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }
    // [END on_new_token]

    /**
     * Schedule async work using WorkManager.
     */
    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        OneTimeWorkRequest work = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().beginWith(work).enqueue();
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     * <p>
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.carpentar)
                        .setContentTitle("my notification")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Myworker class

```
 package com.technolgiya.quickbooktechnichian;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "MyWorker";

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Performing long running task in scheduled job");
        // TODO(developer): add long running task here.
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

and my app-level Gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.technolgiya.quickbooktechnichian"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.9'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the Gradle is syncing properly but the error is showing in compilation time

Error:
error: cannot access InternalTokenProvider
class file for com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider not found
error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Anyone, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are using old dependencies 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'

Try to use the latest one in your **build.gradle:**

implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1

Check this URL - https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#java

Comment: but it seems like it is the problem of messaging dependency because before adding it all worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes but your dependency is not upto date. You have to update them they are old code is not working with them.